# Loggin out from my app when users log out of twitter

Tags: twitter-oauth

I'm working with Oauth and I have one question for the following scenario:

If I'm already logged in with twitter in my app, then the user opens a new tab and browses through twitter and then sign out from twitter (from the twitter tab).

What I want to achieve: once the user logs out of twitter, I want my app to notice this and automatically log out the user from the app.

Is this possible?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK None of the big oauth providers broadcast a log out event you can listen to.

You can achieve close to what you want by setting the timeout of your session cookie shorter.